# Which heroes beaten up by Garou died?

Tags: one-punch-man

Garou has beaten many heroes, but some of them at least in their first beating survived, such as Tank Top Vegetarian. Which heroes beaten up by Garou died?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, **no hero that Garou defeated ever died in the manga**. As noted [here](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Garou):

> Although Garou is a villain and considered evil by most, he possesses a sense of morality: he fights heroes in a way without killing them, but he is okay with others killing heroes.

Comment: When Bang found Charanko and the other heroes lying on the floor the next day, they all seemed dead. Were they alive? Tank Top Master and Mumen Rider werent there.

Comment: @Pablo Yep. In later scenes, Charanko and Tank Top Master was seen talking to Saitama (in the hospital). The Tank Top Army is also not listed as deceased nor dead in the wiki. If they were dead, then it would at least be shown in the manga since subordinates' deaths would inevitably have an effect on Tank Top Master.